# GameObject& rgo = *pa;

Tags: c++

```
GameObject *pgo = new SpaceShip;
Asteroid *pa = new Asteroid;
pgo = pa;
GameObject& rgo = *pa;
```

Assuming GameObject is the base class and SpaceShip and Asteroid have public inheritance with GameOject. I understand the first 2 lines. I don't understand the 3rd line. Why is it you can set the addresses equal, arn't they different classes even if inherited? Then I guess I don't fully understand line 1. Also, I am not sure what line 4 is doing either.

Comment: @sergiol: No `operator=` of any class is being used here. The first three are pointer initialization/assignments, and the last one is a reference initialization.

Comment: lack of attention from my part. I removed my comments in spite of your observation, @BenjaminLindley

Answer (score 1):

If `GameObject` is an interface that both `Asteroid` & `SpaceShip` implement, a variable of type `GameObject*` can point to both of this types.

The 4th line uses a "By Reference" variable declaration to "convert" a pointer type variable to non-pointer.

Comment: I don't think "interfaces" or "implementing" are required for pointer assignment. Plain public inheritance will do. And a "by reference variable" is called a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about C++'s inheritance and polymorphism. Basically, the third line works because an `Asteroid` **is** a `GameObject`, so you can access the `GameObject`-related members of the `Asteroid` using a `GameObject *` pointer.

There may be situations where you need to work with GameObjects, and some other situations where you need to work with Asteroids. In either case you'd use the appropriate pointer, as long the pointer type is within the inheritance hierarchy.

The last line is simply a reference to the object the pointer `pa` points to.